# Price as Configured Displaying as 0.00 on Bundle Product in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I have created a bundled products,

In that product **price as configured** showing zero.

I don't know why its showing zero and please explain me what is the use of **price as configured**.

Answer (score 0):

try this at your template/frontend, bundle/catalog/product/bundle.phtml

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_priceModel  = $_product->getPriceModel();
list($_minimalPriceInclTax, $_maximalPriceInclTax) = $_priceModel->getTotalPrices($_product, null, true, false);
$finalPrice = $_minimalPriceInclTax;
?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var skipTierPricePercentUpdate = true;
        var bundle = new Product.Bundle(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
        var taxCalcMethod = "<?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getConfig()->getAlgorithm($_product->getStore()) ?>";
        var CACL_UNIT_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_UNIT_BASE ?>";
        var CACL_ROW_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_ROW_BASE ?>";
        var CACL_TOTAL_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_TOTAL_BASE ?>";
        //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <!--<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?>
            <span><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span></p>-->
    <?php else: ?>
        <!--<p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?>
            <span><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>-->
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="price-box-bundle">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
```